# Dropdown list value not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, html-select

hi i have gridview that when a row is selected, it populates into textboxes that are used to populate the gridview itself. the last field is a dropdownlist and its not displaying when the gridview is clicked. i set a breakpoint and see that its stuck on the first - 0 index. i dont know why it isnt moving forward... here is the code:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ....

    if (DropDownListCurrency.Items.FindByValue(row.Cells[7].Text.ToString().Trim) != null)
    {
        DropDownListCurrency.SelectedValue = row.Cells[7].Text.ToString().Trim();
    }
    ....
}



<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListCurrency" runat="server" 
        CausesValidation="True"     
        DataSourceID="CurrencyDropDownListDataSource" 
        DataTextField="Currency" DataValueField="Currency_ID"
        AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="&lt;Select&gt;" Enabled="True" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you want take the value from textbox. Will better use DataKeyNames like this inside that event

```
GridViewRow row = GridView.SelectedRow;

int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
```

this work if you have only one value in DataKeyName if you look not there a index if you want have more than one value use this

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["FirstValue"]);

string name = Convert.ToString(GridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["SecondValue"]);
```

Comment: tried this to get the value to display when the row fromt eh gridview is clicked but i think im doing something wrong in the declaration:

DropDownListCurrency.SelectedValue = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["Currency"].ToString();

Comment: Hi try use a trim maybe one value have white spaces for it maybe don't the matching

Comment: the exception its throwing is:

'DropDownListCurrency' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

Comment: even with the trim as:

DropDownListCurrency.SelectedValue = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["Currency"].ToString().Trim();

its still throwing the same error...

Comment: I see could you verify if value from dropdownlist have white spaces

Comment: i think dropdownlist have white spaces because isn't the same Hi__ = Hi

Comment: nope. the table does not have white spaces.

its now saying  NullExceptionReferenceException caught: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: i see well maybe with postback this table lost all values what happen if you repaint this table? you could use a method inside selectedindexchanged to charge again dropdownlist. First not forget clean items. DropDownList.Items.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

Does the DropDownList contains the words that you wanna show displayed?

Comment: yes, its being pulled from a table being referenced the data source. its actually now saying the IF statement has some invalid arguments. is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `AutoPostBack` property to `True`:

it should be :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListCurrency" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" 
        CausesValidation="True"     
        DataSourceID="CurrencyDropDownListDataSource" 
        DataTextField="Currency" DataValueField="Currency_ID"
        AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="&lt;Select&gt;" Enabled="True" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

made a simple error...

called the wrong field was supposed to be value (Currency_ID) and not the text (Currency)

```
DropDownListCurrency.SelectedValue = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["Currency_ID"].ToString().Trim();
```